# Access last replication error message like it's presented in the replication monitor view in SSMS

Tags: .net, sql-server, replication

How to access last replication error message through C# or stored procedure?

I'm able to access Log Viewer and get recent errors this way:

```
 string errorLogPath = null;

            using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Integrated Security=SSPI; Data Source=(local)\SQLEXPRESS"))
            {
                var serverConnection = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection(sqlConnection);
                var server = new Server(serverConnection);
                errorLogPath = server.ErrorLogPath;
            }
```

but this will give me all errors and leave with the problem of filtering. There is a second view in SSMS it's called replication monitor
[image]
and I'd like to access data that is visible there, there it has been already filtered through.

Comment: There's a "simple" trick to these things: hook up a Profiler trace to see what statements SSMS executes to fetch the info. This can get you into some undocumented procedures/tables, but the magic involved is usually fairly minor. (I personally never bother to find out if SMO has happened to add an API for whatever I'm after, as I'm not a fan of SMO in general. Replication tends to be additionally special because most of it is an application built on top of the engine, rather than part of the engine proper, save for the log reading parts.)

Comment: FWIW, last time I had to do something like this it involved `UNION`ing three tables: `MSdistribution_history`, `MSsnapshot_history` and `MSlogreader_history`. All of these are documented.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks, I'll dig into these too. Few moments ago I've found that table ```SELECT *
  FROM [distribution].[dbo].[MSrepl_errors]
  order by [time] DESC```

Comment: If you're only interested in errors specifically, that should do. In my scenario I wanted to know exactly when a replication subscription had finished initializing successfully, and then you need a little more.